# Getting error "cannot resolve symbol getInstance" in firebaseAuth

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ...
    firebaseAuth = new FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
```

getting error in -> getInstance()

```
    }
public void registerUser(){
... 
firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if(task.isSuccessful()){
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Registered successfully",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }else {Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Registered unsuccessful",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}
                }
            });
```

I have synced Firebase with my project properly but getting this error.

Answer (score 9):

Look at the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth) for `FirebaseAuth.getInstance()`. It is a static method that returns the default FirebaseAuth. You don't want to create a new instance, you want the existing default instance.

Change:

```
firebaseAuth = new FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
```

to:

```
firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
```